# Adobe don't run script after PDF is re-opend

Tags: javascript, pdf

Below is my code in Java script for adobe acrobat.
 How do I set my PDF, so the script will always work during printing process? At the moment when I close the document and re-open the code is not executed unless I re-open javaScript "Set Documents Actions" window..
The code works well and its set to run when "document will print"
I need it to be automated. To always execute when a user tries to print it.

```
// Add Watermark ON PRINT Var. Watermark "YES"
var docwtrmrk = this.info.Watermark; // get Watermark variable value : this.info.<Any EPDM Variable can be used as ref.>
var docRev = this.info.Revision; // Get Revision variable Value : this.info.<Any EPDM Variable can be used as ref.>
var cMyText = "NOT APPROVED!!! FOR REFERENCE ONLY" + "\n Printed on: " +  util.printd("dd.mm.yyyy @ HH:MM", new Date) + "\n REVISION NO.: " + docRev;   

if (docwtrmrk == "Yes") {
// Yes, adds watermark
this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nTextAlign:app.constants.align.center,
    cFont: "Helvetica-Bold",
    nScale: 1,
    aColor: color.red,
    nRotation: 45,
    nOpacity: 0.5,
    bOnScreen: true,
    });
app.alert("You are about to print NOT APPROVED Docuement \n Double check with engineering and Document controler  \n USE FOR REF. ONLY", 1);
}
else {} // Dont add watermark
```

Comment: Assuming you have metadata fields defined for "Watermark" and "Revision", the code looks fine to me though you might want to check if those properties exist before attempting to get their values since they are custom fields. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: @joelgeraci the code works, and the variable exists. However, I can't make the code to work on open, on different machines. If I Manually click set document actions it runs the script otherwise it does not.

Comment: Is it possible that those machines have JavaScript turned off? Are they all the same version of 
Acrobat?